# How to call php block function with parameters from a js file?

Tags: magento2, module, category, phtml

I'm new to Magento, and I'm not sure how to make this work. I tried searching a lot but could not find anything related.

I have a block function in my custom module which takes **2 parameter**

```php
    public function getCatURL($category, $subCategory)
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', strtolower($subCategory));
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter(true);
        $catURL = null;
        foreach ($collection as $cat) {
            $parentCat =  $cat->getParentCategory();
            if (strtolower($parentCat->getName()) == strtolower($category)) {
                $catURL = $cat->getURL();
            }
        }

        return $catURL;
    }
```

From my phtml, i want to pass the function instance to my requirejs file, which will call the function with function parameters.

```html
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "retailAssistant": {
                "CatURL": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCatURL; ?>,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I expect to call the cart URL function with parameters based on some action.

```
define([
  "Vendor_Test/js/test",
], function(){
        "use strict";
        return function(config) {
          config.cartURL('men', 'tops');
        }})
```

Running with this throws:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Vendor\Test\Block\Controller::$getCatURL
```

Comment: $block->getCatURL instend of $block->getCatURL($category, $subCategory)

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I can notice.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
       "*": {
           "retailAssistant": {
               "CatURL": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCatURL; ?>,
           }
       }
   }
</script>
```

Should be below because **template Block** is expecting to have ***two*** parameters.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "retailAssistant": {
                "CatURL": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCatURL('men','tops'); ?>",
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You have this somewhere in a js file

```
define([
  "Vendor_Test/js/test",
], function(){
        "use strict";
        return function(config) {
          config.cartURL('men', 'tops');
        }})
```

The above code should be as follows because you are trying to access the `CatURL`, here you could not pass two parameters i.e. category and subcategory.

```
define([
  "Vendor_Test/js/test",
], function(){
        "use strict";
        return function(config) {
            console.log(config);        
            var categoryURL = config.CatURL;
            console.log(categoryURL);
        }})
```

This will help you resolve syntax errors and you can access `CatURL` in JS file.

Clear cache is needed.

Comment: Hi @sandip, Thanks for the answer. 
But I'm looking for a way to send parameters from a js file.